# Create a default constructor in Java

Tags: java

I need to create a method with a default constructor, which sets `name` to an empty string and sets both `credits` and `contactHours` to zero.  How to do it?  Thanks, Pieter.

Comment: Methods don't have constructors. However, assuming you mean a class, then by reading the documentation. This is surely an assignment

Comment: Damn... Such a default constructor smells mutability :(

Answer (score 11):

Methods don't have constructors... classes do. For example:

```
public class Dummy
{
    private int credits;
    private int contactHours;
    private String name;

    public Dummy()
    {
        name = "";
        credits = 0;
        contactHours = 0;
    }

    // More stuff here, e.g. property accessors
}
```

You don't really *have* to set `credits` or `contactHours`, as the `int` type defaults to 0 for fields anyway.

You're likely to want at least one constructor which takes initial values - in which case your parameterless one can delegate to that:

```
public class Dummy
{
    private String name;
    private int credits;
    private int contactHours;

    public Dummy()
    {
        this("", 0, 0);
    }

    public Dummy(String name, int credits, int contactHours)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.credits = credits;
        this.contactHours = contactHours;
    }

    // More stuff here, e.g. property accessors
}
```

Comment: And can't we make the fields final, now that you've provided guaranteed initialization through the constructors?

Comment: @Adriaan: Potentially... but then the object constructed with the default constructor is pretty useless. It's hard to say without more information, basically.

Comment: You are right of course (-: Just thought making fields final a relevant consideration in this context.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Test {
 private String name;
 private int credits;
 private int contactHours;

 public Test {

  this( "", 0, 0);

 }
public Test (String name, int credits, int contactHours) {
 this.name = name;
 this.credits = credits;
 this.contactHours = contactHours;
 }

// more code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Bibabu{
  private String name;
  private int credits;
  private int contactHours;

  public Bibabu(){
    name = "";         // you could also write this.name and so on...
    credits = 0;
    contactHours= 0;
  }

  // more code here

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'M teaching myself Java and had all the other more difficult parts done without problem but this method caused me some problems.  thanks again for the quick response.  Pieter.

Comment: "Bibabu" is a new "default name" to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a constructor:

```
public class Dummy
{
    private int credits = 0;
    private int contactHours=0;
    private String name="";
/*
    public Dummy()
    {
        name = "";
        credits = 0;
        contactHours = 0;
    }
*/  
    // More stuff here, e.g. property accessors
}
```

Comment: I would only default the value of `name` if no other constructors were going to set it - and I'd expect there to be other constructors which *do* take values. (See my edited answer for an example.)

Comment: Even more.. You don't need to initialize integers.

Comment: Thats only true, if initialized with 0 :-). I think, its easier to read, if the attibute is initialized with 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
//constructor
     public Account(int id, double balance, Person owner){

        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.owner = owner;
```